# Gambling expected value riddle

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

A friend of mine gave me this probability riddle i couldn't solve, Maybe you could help me.

Say i go to a casino playing roulette. I always gamble that a black number would pop (probability is: $\frac{18}{38}$) but i made up some rules:

1. I will play some rounds until i'll win at least once.
2. If i lose 11 times in a row, I quit.
3. In the first game i'll play for $1$ coin, Second for $2$, And in the '$i$' games i'll play for $2^{i-1}$ coins.

If i win the casino gives me the same amount of coins i gambled on (And i get back the coins i placed on the roulette)

What is the expected amount of games i would play? What's the probability i would gain coins? (At least $1$ coin)

My tries were a complete failure, My main problem was that: I couldn't figure out how to do i 'stop' when either (1) or (2) is 'completed'.

Comment: What is the amount of work you put into this?

Comment: Sat for about two hours, And got only non-conclusive answers.

Comment: Really? For example what is the probability that case 2 occurs and how much do you "win" in that case?

Comment: Well, You've pointed straight to my Achilles heel.

Comment: "Achilles heel": meaning? I have a conjecture but I would like to know.

Comment: By the way: which course is this homework for?

Comment: I'm not posting home-work, I'm studying alone. This question is surprisingly from a book called 'Discrete Mathhematics' by Nati linel. This one doesn't have answers though.

Comment: And by Achilles heel i meant that i don't have experience on solving questions regarding expected values. So my tries are either a blank page or scribbled with no actual value.

Answer (score 1):

If you win, your net win is $1$ coin.
If you lose, your loss is $1+2+4+\ldots+1024=2047$ coins.
Since loss happens with $(\frac{20}{38})^{11}\approx 0.00085844$, your probability of actually winning (sadly, just one coin) is quite high: $\approx 0.99914$. So your expected "win" in the end is $1\cdot 0.99914-2047\cdot 0.00085844\approx -0.758$ coins.

If the question about the number of rounds was about a fair coin and arbitrarily long lasting games, the answer would be exactly $2$. Howerver, here the precise calculation shows that the expected number of rounds played is $\approx 2.1092988$.

Comment: Actually i win the same amount coins i gambled on. 
And how is the expected number of rounds if would play is ≈$2.1092988$? I mean, How did you calculate it?